# Group-related adjustments to linear regression

Tags: regression

I am using linear regression for a large set of data. I produce a set of weightings for each variable for the data set as a whole. The data however can be broken into subsets relating to different individuals who might have different weightings from the global set due to their different attributes. What I would like from a high-level perspective, but I don't know the name of what I am looking for, is to combine the global weightings for each variable with those of the individual that the data applies to. I don't want to break the data up into independent groups, I would like the weightings to come predominantly from the global data, with small group-related adjustments Does this make sense and is there any recognised technique like this?